# Make external HTTP traffic show as HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, https

I have a site "https:// mysite.com" that loads a popup form over a customer's personal site "http:// example.com" via an iframe into the background.

I am looking for a way to load the external customer's site via https.

For example: "https:// mysite.com/example.com" would load example.com over my site via https, so there wouldn't be any "mixed content" warnings.

I am running IIS, and asp.net application.

Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to subvert security rules that are there for a purpose. Perhaps try opening a new browser tab instead of using an `iframe`. If you are up for something more complicated, I suppose you could write a server-side handler that would read the target page and serve that through your SSL connection.

Comment: Hi @dave, I wish it was that easy. My clients want it to look like the popup is on their site. I have been bouncing around multiple ideas to handle this, from downloading the client's site, to creating a screenshot via ASP.NET and showing the image stored on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write some server-side code to read the target page and then inject that HTML into your page. C# code:

```
public string GetWebpageHtml(string url)
{
  System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
  return wc.DownloadString(url);
}

public ActionResult ServeImage(string imageUrl, string mimeType = "image/jpg")
{
  System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
  var bytes = wc.DownloadData(imageUrl);
  return File(bytes, mimeType);
}
```

In your example you can call that function on `http:// example.com` and place that HTML in your page.

I also created a handler action that should download a remote file and serve it back as a local action. Remember you will also have to convert relative paths to full paths before downloading.

Comment: would the DownloadData() function also include the data for the images, or would I end up with images not found on the server? Thanks!

Comment: You would have to handle images yourself. I wrote an action for you that should grab remote URLs and serve them over your site. You would be responsible for replacing the remote URLs though in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks @dave, I guess that if I used this method, I would just download the basic images to a temp location and then replace the URL's with the download https images?

Comment: That is the problem I am trying to solve with my `ServeImage` action--it should read a remote URL and serve it back as if it came from your domain.E.g. `<img src="https://mysite.com/ServeImage?imageUrl=http%3A%2F%2F%20example.com%2FImage1.jpg" />.` Downloading the images beforehand would work too, but this way you don't have to store them and worry about cleaning up.

Comment: Thanks @dave, this is what I ended up doing!

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you have to proxy the requests through HTTPS (either on your server or some other server). If there are no images/javascript, etc. on the page, it's as simple as what @dave suggests. If there are, then you have to do a little more work to handle all the relative links. If there are POSTs that you have to handle, it gets even more complicated. Depending on the complexity, you may be able to write the code yourself, or you may be able to find some off-the-shelf products that do this.

Comment: There wouldn't be any POSTs on the client's side, it's should just look like their site is in the background. I am trying to find what kind of proxy that I could set up to make this happen. (Key words to look up / google) Thanks!

Comment: A simple proxy handles multiple paths, so every incoming request may need to get sent to it (see global.asax, Application_BeginRequest).  Check to see if the specified url matches what should be proxied (something like Request.Path.StartsWith("/proxy")) and then figure out the actual url you want by changing the scheme to http, and the hostname and path to appropriate url on the target server.  Send that url into HttpWebRequest.Create, call GetResponse on the request, and then copy the response data to the context response.

Comment: Depending on the situation, you may need to copy headers, cookies, etc. both directions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making it look as though you are on your client's site by changing the background of your site, wouldn't it just be easier to actually load the iframe popup on the client's site? It should be relatively simple to write a piece of js like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var node = document.createElement('iframe');
    node.src = 'http://www.google.com';
    node.style = 'position: fixed; width: 80%; height: 80%; margin: auto;'
    document.body.appendChild(node)
</script>
```

And get your client to paste that where appropriate. There are definitely cases where this can't work, of course, but nothing in your question specifies that.

If your client wants to use your form, they would presumably have to link to it or make some change to their site or advertising anyways. Why not have they add this script instead? If your client's site or your site are only available on LANs, then why would they be linking to each other to begin with? So most of the reasons I can think of for not doing 3rd party popups the normal web way don't seem to apply here, at least with the information from the question.

Comment: I actually had this to start with, but when they started to use it, they were complaining that the site wasn't safe (Meaning that they couldn't see the HTTPS in the url) So I had to change it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: So the client doesn't have ssl themselves, and they want you to provide it for them for just one popup? That sucks, I'm sorry. As an aside, they do realize with the solution you are proposing, they will not have their client-side analytics running or anything else for that matter aside from your custom ssl proxy?

Comment: Yeah I know. If they were required to have an SSL, if would have everything very easy, as I would just load whatever page from their site via an iframe, and no mixed content warning / blocked content.  I don't think they care about the client side analytics as of right now.